# Alternative notation to $f(x) = g(x) + c + o(1)$?

Tags: notation, asymptotics

I am familiar with standard notation such as $f(n)\sim g(n)$, $f(n)=O(g(n))$, and $f(n)=o(g(n))$.

As an example, if we define the $n$th harmonic number
$$
H_n = 1+\frac12+\cdots+\frac1n
$$
and we use "log" to mean natural log, then one can show (in increasing order of specificity) that we have
$$
H_n \sim \log n
$$
and in fact, $H_n-\log n$ is bounded, so we have
$$
H_n = \log n + O(1)
$$
and in fact, $H_n-\log n$ approaches a constant (the Euler-Mascheroni constant $\gamma$, about 0.5772), which we could write as
$$
H_n = \log n + \gamma + o(1).
$$
But aesthetically, I don't like that $o(1)$ at the end. I'd like to have a symbol similar to $=$ or $\sim$ that means something like "is additively asymptotic to".

Obviously I'm free to make up such a symbol: I could write $f(n) \sim_a g(n)$ to mean $\lim_{n\to\infty}(f(n)-g(n))=0$, and then I could write
$$
H_n \sim_a \log n + \gamma.
$$
However, this seems like the type of thing that there should already be notation for. Are any of you aware of such notation used by other authors? Or would they pretty much all just write the $o(1)$ at the end?

I Googled the expression "additively asymptotic" and got this:

https://calculus.subwiki.org/wiki/Additively_asymptotic_functions

but very few hits in total.

Comment: Most people would use your last version but drop the little $a.$ Still, every topic that uses many estimates has favorite usages, you should check standard sources.

Comment: Many people would use the last version, but they would be *wrong*. /s